# How to trigger a JavaScript function with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

Ok so I have a PHP document wich saves the contents of a text input how do I trigger a function in a .js file when it's done . I've done the part with the uploading I just can't figure out how to trigger the js function

Comment: Use ajax. You used ajax to upload the the content to server, when finished saving, send a response back to client and execute the function you want.

Comment: I didn't use Ajax and I don't really want to use Ajax

Comment: Why do you not want to use ajax?

Comment: I didn't tag ajax so please stop giving answers with ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
echo "<script src='myScript.js' type ='text/javascript'> myFunction(); </script>";
```

Im not exactly sure what functionality you're trying to get working but if this is supposed to be some kind of data controller where you simply process data, calling echo may give the user a blank screen, so you will want to redirect the user like so

```
header('Location: redirectLocation');
```

Do try to provide more details in future questions, but i hope this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Kris, you can't call a js function from a PHP script. As per my understanding, you should call an AJAX function on click of the button that will call the PHP script and on the success you can call the javascript function that you want to call.